# Console output one time every 40 seconds with interval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use Twitter API in order to retweet.And because Twitter has limitation to 2400 actions per day I decided to limit the retweet to one time every 40 seconds.
I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit using Streaming API.

My problem is that it continuously streams console.log instead of using setInterval.

By stream I mean it outputs console.log multiple times instead of one time.

```
function hastagRetweet() {

    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['#hastag']})

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet,error) {

        var retweetId = tweet.id; // id
        var retweetId_str = tweet.id_str; 
        var tweetTextRetweet = tweet.text; // tweet text


        function twInterval() { 

            console.log('INFO ------- ',tweet.id);
            console.log('INFO ------- ',tweet.text);

        };

        setInterval(twInterval, 1000 * 40);


    });

}
```

Any way of getting the variales data retweetId,retweetId_str,tweetTextRetweet outside stream.on beside inserting them into a mysql table so that every 40 seconds it checks the variables fixed data and executes console.log?

Comment: The problem is twInterval() should be twInterval. You're passing a function, not calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

1. You're trying to start an interval timer in an event handler.  That means that every time the event fires you would be attempting to start a new interval timer and they would pile up.
2. Even if you did sucessfully start up an interval timer, each one would never change it's output since the variables in scope for it never change as it is started up within a given function and the arguments to that function are what they were when it was first called.  Subsequent calls of the function will start a new function not change the arguments on the prior call of the function.
3. You aren't even starting your interval correctly.  As it is, all you're doing is calling the function and passing it's return value to `setInterval()` which does nothing.

If the goal is just to output to the console each stream `tweet` event, then probably what you want is just this:

```
function hastagRetweet() {

    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['#hastag']})

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet,error) {

        var retweetId = tweet.id; // id
        var retweetId_str = tweet.id_str; 
        var tweetTextRetweet = tweet.text; // tweet text

        console.log('INFO ------- ',tweet.id);
        console.log('INFO ------- ',tweet.text);
    });
}
```

You cannot get these variables outside the `.on()` handler.  It's an async callback and the only place they reliably exist is within that handler.

If you can describe in more detail what the end result you're trying to achieve is, we can likely help more specifically.  If you want to do something every 40 seconds, then maybe you need to collect data in some collection (probably an array) and then every 40 seconds evaluate what you have just recently collected.

Here's a method of collecting the events in an array and then evaluating them every 40 seconds:

```
function hastagRetweet() {

    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['#hastag']});
    var tweets = [];

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet,error) {
        tweets.push({id: tweet.id, str: tweet.id_str, text: tweet.text});
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        // evaluate the tweets in the tweets array every 40 seconds

        // do something with them
        for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
            // tweets[i].id
            // tweets[i].str
            // tweets[i].text
        }

        // reset the tweets array
        tweets.length = 0;
    }, 40 * 1000);

}
```

Please note that once you call `hastagRetweet()`, it will run forever.

Comment: Like I said above current code streams continuously for each event, I want to limit it to an interval. I'm a bit tired and don't know how to explain it more.

Comment: @Alex_TNT - limit WHAT to an interval?  Your question does not describe what you are trying to do well enough for us to make a specific recommendation on how to achieve some goal.  Stream events occur whenever they occur.  You can't control that.  See what I added to the last paragraph of my answer about collecting events into an array and then evaluating them every so often.

Comment: Yes exactly what you said in the last paragraph

Comment: @Alex_TNT - I added a code example for that last paragraph.

Comment: One more question. How do you call the variables from the array?

Comment: @Alex_TNT -  It's an array of objects.  `tweets[n]` is an object with properties `.id`, `.str` and `.text`.  So, you'd access the id property of the first element in the array as `tweets[0].id`.  And, `tweets.length` tells you how long the array is.

Comment: Thank you now makes sense, I think I need to go to sleep. Thank you again